# Python, Flask, ffmpeg video streaming: Video does not work in Firefox

Tags: python, flask, ffmpeg

I am writing a preview portion for video management system, it works like a charm in chrome with standard  tag but firefox does not recognize MIME type for some reason and it bugs me a lot.

Here is my stream class:

```
class Stream:
    run = False
    FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    overlay = ffmpeg.input("somelogo.png")

    def __init__(self, camid):
        camUtil = CameraUtil()
        self.camid = camid
        self.streamurl = camUtil.get_stream_from_id(self.camid)['streamURL']
        print(self.streamurl)
        self.args = ffmpeg.input(self.streamurl)
        # vcodec="libvpx",
        # acodec="libvorbis",
        self.args = ffmpeg.output(self.args, "-",
                                  f="matroska",
                                  vcodec="copy",
                                  acodec="copy",
                                  blocksize="1024",
                                  # strftime="1",
                                  # segment_time="60",
                                  # segment_format="matroska"
                                  preset="ultrafast",
                                  metadata="title='test'"
                                  )
        self.args = ffmpeg.get_args(self.args)
        print(self.args)
        self.pipe = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg'] + self.args,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
                                     #stderr=self.FNULL)

    def dep_stream(self):
        def gen():
            try:
                f = self.pipe.stdout
                byte = f.read(1024)
                while byte:
                    yield byte
                    byte = f.read(1024)
            finally:
                self.pipe.kill()

        return Response(gen(), status=200,
                        mimetype='video/webm',
                        headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                 "Content-Type": "video/webm",
                                 })
```

My html playback portion:

`<video id="live_page_player" id="video" preload="auto" autoplay width="1280" height="720">
      <source src="/stream/{{ camid }}" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
      YOUR BROWSER DOES NOT SUPPORT HTML5, WHAT YEAR ARE YOU FROM?!
    </video>`

Firefox says "No video with supported format and MIME type found" and in console it says

error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)

Did I do something dumb?! Or am I missing something, because it works google chrome like a charm

I need fresh eyes.

Help plez

Comment: If you go to `about:config` in the firefox browser, what is the value of `media.mediasource.webm.enabled`? If it's `false`, does changing it to `true` change the behavior? Note that this value could be set to `false` for good reason, and changing it may cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @sytech Thank you, but it did not help. I have tried to re-encode the stream into full webm(I know that it is TECHNICALLY matroska, but I used libvpx-vp9 and libopus for sound) and it started to work, but it is pretty slow, so il be looking into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after bashing my head around, I decided to check out the console(yes I know)

I found that firefox throws NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR, after vigorous googling I have found that raw matroska is not supported by firefox(or rather they don't let you play it for some reason) while google chrome does support it.

The solution was actually pretty simple, you gotta re-encode the stream with vcodec libvpx-vp9 or vp8 and acoded libopus or libvorbis

The ffmpeg for python syntax would look like this:

```
self.args = ffmpeg.output(self.args, "-",
                              f="webm",
                              vcodec="libvpx-vp9",
                              acodec="loboupus",
                              blocksize="1024",
                              # strftime="1",
                              # segment_time="60",
                              # segment_format="matroska"
                              preset="ultrafast",
                              metadata="title='test'"
                              )
```

Note that this eats the CPU quite heavily, Im still playing around with it but this is the solution!